# Modal not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, bootstrap-4

I am using rails 5 and bootstrap 4. I have also installed: gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'

View code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Automate your conditions
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">What do you want to optimize for?</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <%= link_to 'Popularity', '#' %>
          <%= link_to 'Inventory turns', '#' %>
          <%= link_to 'Seasonality', '#' %>
          <%= link_to 'Profitability', '#' %>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
$('#myModal').modal();
```

If i click on the "Automate your conditions" button, nothing happens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data-target` attribute must make reference to the `id` of the modal div you want to show when the button is clicked.

You could try setting both attributes with the same reference `data-target` - `id`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Automate your conditions
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  ...
</div>
```

Also, if you set `$('#myModal').modal();` the modal will be "fired" when the page loads, so you can try commenting that piece of code.